# SQL Query: calculating percentage

Tags: sql

If I wanted to find the percentage of people that are from the zip code area of 12345, I would take the number of people with that zip code and divide it from the total number of people… what am I missing in the example query below? I can’t figure out how to display the percentage correctly. It just keeps saying 0%.

```
select (count(P.PERSON_ID) / (select count(*) from PERSON P)) * 100.00
as “12345 Zip Code Percentage”
from PERSON P
where P.ZIP = '12345'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're dividing an integer by a larger integer. The result is always going to be zero. Instead, multiply the first count by 100.0 *before* division. That converts the first count to a floating point number which, when divided by an integer, will give a floating point number and thus the percentage you need.

Comment: Wow... I feel a little silly. That makes sense and it works. At least that was a simple mistake and fix :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing an integer division. If the result is lower to 1, it will always display 0 * 100.00, so always 0. If you want an accurate percentage, you need to cast one of the variables as a float.

```
select (count(P.PERSON_ID) / CAST ((select count(*) from PERSON P) As Float)) * 100.00
as “12345 Zip Code Percentage”
from PERSON P
where P.ZIP = '12345'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to choose the number of decimal points you could also incorporate `ROUND()` as follows:

```
,ROUND(CAST(COUNT(var1) AS FLOAT)/COUNT(var2),[# decimals]) AS 'mypercentage'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (P.SubSet * 100.00)/p.Total AS "12345 Zip Code Percentage"
  FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN ZIP = '12345' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) Subset,
               COUNT(*) Total
          FROM PERSON 
       ) P
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i added extra condition to avoid divide by 0 error:

```
select 
    CASE 
    WHEN  (select count(*) from PERSON P) > 0 THEN (CAST(count(P.PERSON_ID) As Decimal) / CAST((select count(*) from PERSON P)As Decimal)) * 100.00
    ELSE 0 END
    as “12345 Zip Code Percentage”
    from PERSON P
    where P.ZIP = '12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select AVG(CASE WHEN ZIP = '12345' 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END) * 100.00 as “12345 Zip Code Percentage”
from PERSON P
```